# What's difference between "I like it." and " I like that."?

Tags: differences

What's difference between "I like it." and " I like that."? I wonder the difference.

Comment: Have you looked up the difference between *that* and *it*?  They are both pronouns, but with different meanings.

Comment: Is there the defferent expression between them?

Comment: This is a hairy topic. No native speaker could give you a straight answer; I'm sorry. There are some flimsy patterns (rather than rules) which I could tentatively delineate for you unless someone surprises me (and the rest of us) with something totally brilliant in the course of the next hour or so. Feel free to remind me.